# Python problem with downloading links from www

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with the code and I admit I don't understand what is happening. I have from the download page 13 links. Up to this point `self.img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.link_photo)` everything is ok.  Further after displaying 5 it stops working. It seems to be doing something strange here. It seems to be doing something strange here 'self.imgURL = self.img.get_attribute('srcset')'.Can someone help me fix this code? Thank you very much for your help.

```
    # Download a link of each photo
    self.table_of_mini_photo = []
    for num, i in enumerate(range(1, int(self.total)+20)):
        self.link_photo = f'//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[{i}]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img'
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[4]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[6]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[7]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[8]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[10]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[12]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[17]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[15]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[16]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
    # //*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[15]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
        try:
            print(self.link_photo)
            self.img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.link_photo)
            print(self.img)
            self.imgURL = self.img.get_attribute('srcset')
            print(self.imgURL)
            self.table_of_mini_photo.append(self.imgURL)
        except:
            pass
```

The console result confirms that I get 13 'selenium : that is links' but physically I get 5. Behind the commented in code are XPath that I download.

```
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="671dace6-a8c2-4204-a164-1266b9385073")>
https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/9li55l5fl99q3-PL/image;s=100x0;q=50 100w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/9li55l5fl99q3-PL/image;s=200x0;q=50 200w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/9li55l5fl99q3-PL/image;s=300x0;q=50 300w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/9li55l5fl99q3-PL/image;s=400x0;q=50 400w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/9li55l5fl99q3-PL/image;s=600x0;q=50 600w
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="431518f9-0ee5-4317-a200-39bd7840939e")>
https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/mbbgmgrg6z343-PL/image;s=100x0;q=50 100w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/mbbgmgrg6z343-PL/image;s=200x0;q=50 200w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/mbbgmgrg6z343-PL/image;s=300x0;q=50 300w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/mbbgmgrg6z343-PL/image;s=400x0;q=50 400w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/mbbgmgrg6z343-PL/image;s=600x0;q=50 600w
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[4]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="07505827-b5fb-4af1-92f5-5391fdbf12d2")>
https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/w53tb2o5ili71-PL/image;s=100x0;q=50 100w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/w53tb2o5ili71-PL/image;s=200x0;q=50 200w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/w53tb2o5ili71-PL/image;s=300x0;q=50 300w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/w53tb2o5ili71-PL/image;s=400x0;q=50 400w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/w53tb2o5ili71-PL/image;s=600x0;q=50 600w
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[5]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[6]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="0d7a591e-e318-41c6-9e2f-2519bbaeb212")>
https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/yjsjx3lv5hnx-PL/image;s=100x0;q=50 100w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/yjsjx3lv5hnx-PL/image;s=200x0;q=50 200w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/yjsjx3lv5hnx-PL/image;s=300x0;q=50 300w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/yjsjx3lv5hnx-PL/image;s=400x0;q=50 400w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/yjsjx3lv5hnx-PL/image;s=600x0;q=50 600w
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[7]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="79ea57a4-9bd5-4213-93c8-acceb60094a0")>
https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/5gs5bqemn8wr-PL/image;s=100x0;q=50 100w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/5gs5bqemn8wr-PL/image;s=200x0;q=50 200w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/5gs5bqemn8wr-PL/image;s=300x0;q=50 300w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/5gs5bqemn8wr-PL/image;s=400x0;q=50 400w,
        https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/5gs5bqemn8wr-PL/image;s=600x0;q=50 600w
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[8]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="d4c89d12-0b89-42bd-8984-8ca1be8f106e")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[10]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="5953e136-712e-43d4-a36f-55ddcc460594")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[11]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[12]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="80e8fd03-4fe2-4797-9b4b-1228f8f6a706")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[13]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="2b0d5ded-6480-4c43-87c2-ef9eece4f6e4")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[14]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="f480c79e-2b10-4379-8b60-26377d36e936")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[15]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="a04b82e4-7021-47d5-8746-f08765fe7b17")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[16]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="3cc93e75-aea9-4366-a1eb-c240fee343ca")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[17]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8cb74bec440fc1d3621f9a5a995c27d6", element="57e77c14-1ef4-4732-bc2f-b938b1841820")>

//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[18]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[19]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[20]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[21]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[22]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[23]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[24]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[25]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[26]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[27]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[28]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[29]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[30]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[31]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[32]/a/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img
```

Comment: I think we're going to need a link to the page to see what's going on. From what I can tell, it looks like some of your loop indices don't have an element there that matches that XPath. You're eating the exceptions thrown so you don't see the error message but you can look at the logs and see that some are missing.

Comment: With a look at the page I'm sure I can come up with a better locator that will find all of the images and then you can just loop through the existing images instead of trying to force locators using an looped index when some images may not be present.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help.
I'm posting the link, it's a Polish site with car sales. I chose the brand Porsche because I am interested in this brand :D, model 944. 
https://www.olx.pl/d/motoryzacja/samochody/porsche/?search%5Bfilter_enum_model%5D%5B0%5D=944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the 911 Turbo. :)

I found a simple CSS selector that retrieves all images.

```
div[type='list'] > div > img
```

Also, you are pulling `srcset` which is a bunch of different sizes of the same image. If all you want is an image, you can just pull `src` and get a single image so you don't have to parse the string, etc.

```
self.imgURL = self.img.get_attribute('src')
```

The updated code loops through only the retrieved images, grabs and prints the 'src', and then appends it to the list.

```
# Download a link of each photo
self.table_of_mini_photo = []
for img in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[type='list'] > div > img")
    imgURL = img.get_attribute('src')
    print(imgURL)
    self.table_of_mini_photo.append(imgURL)
```

Comment: Me too but for now I have a 986 with 98' :), Thx for the help.

Comment: Ok :) i did it.